# Adding APNS cert to Google Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

When trying to add the APNS .p12 certificate file to Google Firebase to allow iOS push notifications it returns an error saying "An unknown server error occurred" and posts a 500 error in the developer console.

[a link to show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWa3h.png)

- I have double checked that I am exporting the certificate, not the key.
- I have tried to add the cert in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on both PC and Mac.
- I have also tried both the Dev Cert and Prod Cert uploads for Firebase and both return this same error.

Comment: This was probably a temporary issue 3 years ago on Firebase backend, but now uploading a .p12 works consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using the .p12 certificate. Firebase says that it accepts either .p12 or .p8. Using the .p8 worked immediately.